# GoTo statement behavior in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, goto, onerror

I have a structure in Jmeter that looks like that

```
  Transaction 1
    On Error GoTo Transaction 1
  Transaction 2
    On Error GoTo Transaction 1
  Transaction 3  
    On Error GoTo Transaction 1
```

To get the On Error GoTo, I used a If Controler with a Module Controler pointing to T1 inside

So the expected behavior on error let's say in Transaction 2 would be:

**T1 - T2Error - T1 - T2 -T3**

Instead I get that behavior:

**T1 - T2Error - T1 - T3**

As if it goes to T1 but then continue normally the flow.

Any idea on how I can get the behavior I expect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Module Controller can only execute the referenced [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment), it will not really "go to" your T1 and the test will not start over. It will **call** T1 and continue. See [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation.

If I'm correctly getting your point you should substitute your Module Controller with [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler configured to `Go to next iteration of Current Loop`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Exactely do what I want. You made my day